# What's the .driver-metadata file used for in Android Things?

Tags: android, iot, android-things

I've noticed in the Android Things `contrib-drivers` repo there's a few of these `.driver-metadata` files (one in each different driver folder). Does anyone know what they're for?

Example: https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/rainbowhat/.driver-metadata

Thanks!

Comment: I'm asking because I'm working on a driver and I'd like to know if I should create them or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could that Google use a tool to autogenerate the table of available drivers in their README of the repository.

You can see from this commit: https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/commit/194d09e8f4f0e0d5f8e0eef78ea26bdc8fa4fb5a

That each of the drivers created the type from the `.driver-metadata` file:

`TYPE="RGB LED strip"`

matches the column `type` in the README table:

`| RGB LED strip |`

Further if a `.driver-metadata` has another key,value of `sample` this is also in the table (and if it doesn't then there is no sample link).

This would mean (Google's side) if a driver was added/updated you would get automatic updates elsewhere.

This is just theoretical, you need a Googler to confirm :-)

Comment: Yes, they are used for auto-generating content in the README :)